# C++ Получить имена сетевых устройств

Tags: c++, ip, winsock2

Есть функция для получения IP адресов сетевых устройств.

Как получить их имена

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include<fstream>
#include <regex>

// Для корректной работы freeaddrinfo в MinGW
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

//#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")


    std::string PcName; //Название компютера в сети


    struct sIP{
        std::string ip;
        std::string name;
    };
    std::vector<sIP>IpList; //Достные сетевіе интерфейсы



//Получить один из ІР первый попавшыйся обяычно нужный Остальные записать в масив
std::string GetIP()
{
    PcName = ""; //Название компютера в сети
    IpList.clear(); //Достные сетевіе интерфейсы

    const int winsock_version = 2;
    std::string out = "WinSock ERR";
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (!WSAStartup(winsock_version/*WINSOCK_VERSION*/, &wsaData))
        {
        char chInfo[64];
        if (!gethostname(chInfo, sizeof(chInfo)))
        {
            hostent *sh;
            sh = gethostbyname((char*)&chInfo);
            PcName = chInfo; //Имя пк
            //std::cout<<chInfo<<"<<\n";

            if (sh != NULL)
            {
                int nAdapter = 0;
                while (sh->h_addr_list[nAdapter])
                {
                    struct sockaddr_in adr;
                    memcpy(&adr.sin_addr, sh->h_addr_list[nAdapter], sh->h_length);
                    //sh->h_name
                    out = inet_ntoa(adr.sin_addr);
                    sIP temp1;
                    temp1.ip = out;

                    temp1.name = "no ralisation";
                    IpList.push_back(temp1);



                    nAdapter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    WSACleanup();
    return out;
}






int main()
{
    GetIP();
    std::cout<<"PC name: "<< PcName<< std::endl;
    for(int i = 0;i < IpList.size();i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"PC name: " << IpList[i].name<< " IP:"<< IpList[i].ip<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: И что же происходит? Как вы передали в функцию инициализации просто число 2?) Проверяйте ошибки вызывая GetLastError

Comment: GetLastError допишу потом. А в чём проблема кроме того что winsock_version должно быть глобальным и влиять на все сокеты?.

Comment: Ищите аналог в винде для [getifaddrs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getifaddrs) и [if_nameindex](https://linux.die.net/man/3/if_nameindex)

Comment: спасибо попробую